# How to maximize the area under -log(x) curve?

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, equation, logarithm

I'm trying to get the `x` and `y` coordinates for which the area under the curve: `y=-15.7log(x)+154.94` is maximum. I would like to compute this in R or Python. Can someone please help me to find it?

---

*Background*: I have data points of sales (y) vs prices (x). I tried fitting a log curve in R: `lm(formula = y ~ log(x))` which gave me the above equation. I'm trying to increase the revenue which is the product of sales and prices. Hence the rectangular area under the curve should be maximized.

Comment: The area at a point is infinitesimally small. Can you more clearly explain your objective? Show us the math (or pseudocode) that reflects your intended behavior.

Comment: This is an optimization problem. You can minimize chi square, do a curve fit, maximize log likelihood, etc etc to produce optimized values of x, y. Look up scipy docs "scipy.optimize".

Comment: @aryamccarthy I have data points of sales vs prices. I tried fitting a log curve. For this I took lm(formula = y ~ log(x)) which gave me the intercepts. This gave me the equation: y=-15.7log(x)+154.94. Here y is the sales and x is the price. I'm trying to increase the revenue which is the product of sales and prices. Hence the rectangular area under the curve should be maximum and i want to find those points of x and y for which the area under this equation is maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**R solution**

```
# objective function should be minimized
NegArea <- function (x) x * (15.7 * log(x) - 154.94)
# sketch this function: there is a minimum
curve(NegArea, from = 0, to = 10000)
# use optimize()
optimize(NegArea, c(4000, 8000))
```

---

**Analytical solution**

First derivative is:

```
15.7 + 15.7 * log(x) - 154.94
```

Set it to zero and solve it:

```
x = 7106.675
```

This agrees with R result.

Comment: Why should I minimize the objective function? i need to find the x and y coordinates for which the rectangle are under the function should be maximum.

Comment: So for this I'm getting an output of 7106 as minimum. So the value of X for which the area of rectangle under equation y=-15.7log(x)+154.94 is 7106?

Answer (score 0):

That is no programming question but a mathematics question and if I get the function in your question right, the answer is "wherever the graph hits the x-axis".
But I think that was not what you wanted. Maybe you want the rectangle between O(0,0) and P(x, y)?
Than you still should simply use a cas and a-level mathematics:
`A = x*(-15.7log(x)+154.94)`

Comment: The equation is correct and I want to find the points for which the rectangular area between O(0,0) and P(x, y) is maximum. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: It is decreasing function.

Comment: It is not monotonically. It starts from 0 goes up and because log(x) increases forever, it hit y=0 again at x=e^(7747/785) or 19317.94641538007
A(e^(7747/785)) = 1693225.98something

And you will really want to solve this with math and not by calculating the value of A for every x from 0 to 19317.

Comment: please not is is -log(x). hence it is a decreasing function.

Comment: I noted it and it is the reason why it does not increase from 0 to inf but goes to -inf after some time. You really should ask this question in a math forum. It is implemented hundreds of times in every CAS and you need neither R nor Python.

Comment: Why should I? There are hundreds of CAS that can do this for me? For this special equation, we don't need a programm that can automaticly calculate every equation. The question is how THIS equation can be solved and the answer is: "use a CAS!"

Comment: It would be something else if we were looking for a universal solution to methos LIKE this.

Comment: Didn't I answer the question? Manoj Kumar asked where the area under the graph is max and I answered that. Manoj Kumar wanted to know where the rectangle is max and I answered that too. I just did not need Python to answe the question. So is it the question that is missplaced or the answer?